# Why is comparison between undefined variables true in bash?

Tags: bash

I am learning if sentence of bash.
I test comparison with undefined variable. Its return value was 0.

I would expect this to be false, much as how any comparison to NaN is always false.
Could you explain why the result of this comparison is true?

```
unset UDEFINED_VAR_0
unset UDEFINED_VAR_1

echo "compare \${UDEFINED_VAR_0} = \${UDEFINED_VAR_1}"
[ ${UDEFINED_VAR_0} = ${UDEFINED_VAR_1} ]
IF_RESULT=$?
if [ ${IF_RESULT} -eq 0 ]; then
  COMMENT="success to compare \${UDEFINED_VAR_0} = \${UDEFINED_VAR_1}"
else
  COMMENT="failure to compare \${UDEFINED_VAR_0} = \${UDEFINED_VAR_1}"
fi
echo "$COMMENT"
echo "result is ${IF_RESULT}"
```

The output was following,

```
compare ${UDEFINED_VAR_0} = ${UDEFINED_VAR_1}
success to compare ${UDEFINED_VAR_0} = ${UDEFINED_VAR_1}
result is 0
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Quote your parameter expansions, read [this information](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) and if you still have questions, come back.

Comment: Why do you need tens of lines to ask this question, as opposed to, say, three?

Comment: ...and in what world are two empty strings *not* equal? I don't see why you think the results you get are unreasonable at all.

Comment: @chepner : Thank you for telling me the information. I read it before I post next.

Comment: @Charles Duffy : Thank you for answering. Next time, I try to focus more and use less code. I mistakenly imagined that undefined variables are corresponding with NaN existence. Comparison NaN is false, I suppose. That is the reason I felt it was strange. Anyway thank you again.

Comment: I think the question is much improved with editing; thank you for paying attention to that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **don't quote**, then:

```
[ $empty_var1 = $empty_var2 ]
```

becomes

```
[ = ]
```

which is parsed as shorthand for:

```
[ -n = ]
```

which checks whether `=` is a non-empty string, which it is, so it returns true.

---

By contrast, if you **do quote**, then:

```
[ "$empty_var1" = "$empty_var2" ]
```

becomes

```
[ '' = '' ]
```

which is true, because these strings are equal.

---

If you want to distinguish between *unset* and *set to an empty value*, then use `${var+val}`:

```
if [ -z "$var1" ]; then
  if [ -n "${var1+set}" ]; then
    echo "var1 is explicitly set to an empty (zero-byte) value"
  else
    echo "var1 is unset"
  fi
else
  echo "var1 is set to a non-empty value"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for kind and deep instruction. It was very educational for me. As you mentioned above, my question is not good but your answer is great. I wonder I should delete this post because of my poor question or leave it because your great answer. Maybe I leave it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In case 1 and 2 you are creating syntax errors, since you have not used quotes. The code

```
[ "comparison_undefined_var" = ${UNDEFINED_VAR_0} ]
```

will translate to

```
[ "comparison_undefined_var" = ]
```

which causes the 'unary operator expected' error message, since the '=' operator is a binary operator and expects a second argument on the right hand side, which is missing here.

If you use quotes like follows

```
[ "comparison_undefined_var" = "${UNDEFINED_VAR_0}" ]
```

this will be translated to

```
[ "comparison_undefined_var" = "" ]
```

With that you will avoid the error message and the code will return false without any error.

Likewise, in case 3 and 4, the code

```
[ ${UNDEFINED_VAR} = ${UNDEFINED_VAR} ]
```

will translate to

```
[ = ]
```

and I would have expected an error message as well. However, Charles Duffy has pointed out in his answer that the code translates to

```
[ -n = ]
```

which is a test whether the string "=" is non-empty. It is non-empty and will return true. However, this is not, what you wanted to test. Instead, I suggest to write

```
[ "${UNDEFINED_VAR_0}" = "${UNDEFINED_VAR_1}" ]
```

instead. This will translate to

```
[ "" = "" ]
```

and will return true.